# ресурсный контроллер

Tags: php, laravel

почему не видит $request->hasFile('newphoto') в ресурсном контроллере?

```
if ($request->hasFile('newphoto')) {
            $destinationPath = 'news';
            $ph = $request->file('newphoto');
            $fileName  = $ph->getClientOriginalName();
            if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists($destinationPath)) {
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory($destinationPath, 0775, true); //creates directory
            }
            Storage::disk('public')->put($destinationPath.'/'.$fileName, file_get_contents($ph));
            $request->image  = $destinationPath.'/'. $fileName;
        } else $request->image = '';
```

хотя если выводить так $request->newphoto показывает что в инпут было добавлено фото

Answer (score 0):

Вполне возможно, что `$request->hasFile` не срабатывает потому, что вы не указали в атрибутах формы необходимый для передачи файлов `enctype`.

Если у вас в html атрибутах формы, через которую отправляются данные не указано

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

то добавьте его.